# open a overlay with form onFocus in react

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Hello I've searching a way to display a overlay with a form when I give the focus to a certain input field. I want to do this using react. How can I do this?

**my code**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


class Middle extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            posts: []
        }
    }

    render() {

        function popup_ques(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("now the overlay should appear");
        }

        return (
            <div className="middle_div">

                <input className='post_data_input' placeholder="Ask your question here" ref="postTxt"
                       onClick={popup_ques}/>

            </div>


        );
    }
}

export default Middle;
```

I have written a function to display an alert when the input field is clicked.. instead of the alert I want to display a transparent overlay with a form.

I want to do something like this

http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_overlay

Thanks inadvance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [display a overlay when input is clicked in react](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42130822/display-a-overlay-when-input-is-clicked-in-react)

Comment: @CraZy It seems that you have asked same question twice. You should delete one of the question. BTW I have posted answer on both of your question.

Answer (score 0):

So here i have written code to change the className of the side bar. Every time you call toggleSideBar it will change className from hideSideBar to showSideBar and vice versa. css for hideSideBar and showSideBar should be written as in the link of code school. Hope it will work.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


class Middle extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      sidebar: 'hideSideBar',
      posts: [],
    }
  }

  toggleSideBar() {
    if(this.state.toggleBar === 'showSideBar') {
      this.setState({ toggleBar: 'hideSideBar' });
    } else {
      this.setState({ toggleBar: 'showSideBar' });        
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="middle_div">
        <input
          className='post_data_input'
          placeholder="Ask your question here"
          ref="postTxt"
          onClick={this.toggleSideBar.bind(this)}
        />

        <div className={this.state.sidebar} />
          // This will be the sidebar
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Middle;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a react component based on link you have given in question.
I hope this will help you in somewhat way to achieve what you want.

```js
class Test extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            style : {
                width : 350
            }
        };
        this.openNav = this.openNav.bind(this);
        this.closeNav = this.closeNav.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        document.addEventListener("click", this.closeNav);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        document.removeEventListener("click", this.closeNav);
    }

    openNav() {
        const style = { width : 350 };
        this.setState({ style });
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
        document.addEventListener("click", this.closeNav);
    }

    closeNav() {
        document.removeEventListener("click", this.closeNav);
        const style = { width : 0 };
        this.setState({ style });
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#F3F3F3";
    }

    render() {
        return (
          <div>
          <h2>Fullscreen Overlay Nav Example</h2>
<p>Click on the element below to open the fullscreen overlay navigation menu.</p>
<p>In this example, the navigation menu will slide in, from left to right:</p>
<span style={{fontSize:30,cursor:"pointer"}} onClick={this.openNav}>&#9776; open</span>
            <div
                ref       = "snav"
                className = "overlay"
                style     = {this.state.style}
            >
                <div className = "sidenav-container">
                    <div className = "text-center">
                      <h2>Form</h2>
                      <p>This is a sample input form</p>
                    </div>
                    <a
                        href      = "javascript:void(0)"
                        className = "closebtn"
                        onClick   = {this.closeNav}
                    >
                        ×
                    </a>
                  <div className = "list-group">
                      {/*your form component goes here */}
                      {this.props.children}
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Test/>,
  document.getElementById('test')
);
```

```css
.overlay {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.9);
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.overlay-content {
    position: relative;
    top: 25%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.overlay a {
    padding: 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.overlay a:hover, .overlay a:focus {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.overlay .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 45px;
    font-size: 60px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .overlay a {font-size: 20px}
  .overlay .closebtn {
    font-size: 40px;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
  }
}

.overlay h2, .overlay p {
  color:white;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>


<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: when I try to import this I get this error.
Uncaught Error: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element.

Comment: Can you give more details about error? It is working in the code snippet I have provided.