# HTML Checkbox and Agree to terms to access/view page

Tags: html

I'm designing an page user post submission page for my website and I would like to create a checkbox agreement to the terms for the user to access/view the page. (E.g the page is blurred beforehand or something similar)

Is this possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Kindly share what you've attempted so we will know how to help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to implement this is with **Overlay**. So, you can create an overlay that will be above the content that you want to hide or blur out. Content like checkbox agreement to the terms can be on the (above the) overlay and you can use a state variable or something to remove or keep the overlay depending upon the state.

This might be helpful: [How can one create an overlay in css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9724035/how-can-one-create-an-overlay-in-css)

To give you some code additional information would be helpful to answer this question better like What are you using React, Angular, or something else.